# Facebook Graph API get picture of url

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api

Does anybody of you know ho to get the image (thumbnail) from an url you normally paste on your wall?

I have an URL and I want the image that Facebook is using for the post.

Either JavaScript or PHP will do.

Comment: I think you want to know how facebook show the images presents at the posted url, i guess they were parsing the content of the url then using the image.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this page helps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

It has links to some of Facebook's Tools.